# java.time.DateTimeFormat Unexpected Behavior

Tags: java, java-time

In Java 8 java.time package, using [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) with [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 28);
date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE).equals("2015-W53-1");
```

as expected, but

```
date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY'-W'ww'-'e")).equals("2016-W01-2");
```

That is a full week later! Why? What incantation would make my custom pattern work the same as the built-in pattern?

Comment: Odd - both give 2015-W53-1 for me... can you show a short but complete program that just prints out both, for the same date? That's what I've got... (just the lines that you've got, but using `System.out.println` instead of `equals` - the main point being that it's a simple console app I can just compile and run without any other dependencies).

Comment: Well, 2015 is 52 or 53 weeks long depending on whether you begin the week with Monday or Sunday. As far as I can tell, the ISO week calculates with Monday as the first day in week. If you platform has Sunday as first day, that might cause the difference. I don't know how to fix it though.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 Uses Builder

Here is the implementation for [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE). The source uses a [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) ([`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)) rather than a coded String.

From [this OpenJDK source code for Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/158f42f97968/src/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java) which appears to be current development version after Java 8 Update 72 (I'm not fluent with the OpenJDK site).

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_WEEK_DATE;
    static {
        ISO_WEEK_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
                .appendLiteral("-W")
                .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
                .appendLiteral('-')
                .appendValue(DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendOffsetId()
                .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
    }
```

## First Day Of Week

I do not know the exact nature of the problem, but I suspect it is the definition of the first day of week. The ISO standard says Monday starts the week. It seems `.appendValue(DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)` line in code above is making that a fact though I do not know why that would be necessary as the `IsoChronology` is specified in the last line above.

## Locale

Anyways, the problem is certainly contained within [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Here is an example showing the Germany locale generates `2015-W53-1` while the United States locale generates: `2016-W01-2`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of ( 2015 , 12 , 28 );
String builtIn = localDate.format ( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ); // 2015-W53-1

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "YYYY'-W'ww'-'e" );

formatter = formatter.withLocale ( Locale.GERMANY );  // 2015-W53-1
String custom = localDate.format ( formatter );
System.out.println ( "formatter.locale: " + formatter.getLocale () + " | localDate: " + localDate + " | builtIn: " + builtIn + " | custom: " + custom );

formatter = formatter.withLocale ( Locale.US );  // 2016-W01-2
custom = localDate.format ( formatter );
System.out.println ( "formatter.locale: " + formatter.getLocale () + " | localDate: " + localDate + " | builtIn: " + builtIn + " | custom: " + custom );
```

> formatter.locale: de_DE | localDate: 2015-12-28 | builtIn: 2015-W53-1 | custom: 2015-W53-1
>
> formatter.locale: en_US | localDate: 2015-12-28 | builtIn: 2015-W53-1 | custom: 2016-W01-2

Answer (score 1):

Similar question answered here: [Inconsistent `w` symbol formatting from joda time to java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367637/inconsistent-w-symbol-formatting-from-joda-time-to-java-time)

Seems like the issue is with Locale as Basil mentioned.